# Form data not posting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have this form down below for which I'm using the jquery validation plugin, but when I try to post data through the php nothing happens, no errors are thrown, nothing. Is there something I'm doing wrong? For simplicity I've excluded the text and the rules from the jquery validation.

I'm also open to changing my validation if there is something else that works. I'm using miranda js to get some JSON data so I'm not sure if that's messing stuff up.

```
    <form class="prize-form" id="prize-form" name="registration">
        <h2>Înscrie codul de sub capac/cheiță!</h2>
        <label for="birthday"></label>
        <input class="-white" type="date" max="2000-07-16"name="birthday" id="birthday">
        <label for="phone_number"></label>
        <input class="-white" type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
        <label for="cod"></label>
        <input class="-white" type="text" name="code" id="code">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input class="-white" type="email" name="email" id="email">
        <label class="checkarea">
            <input class="-white" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox1">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="checkarea">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1[]" id="checkbox1">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="checkarea">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" id="checkbox2">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        <button id="submit" data-popup-open="popup-1" type="submit" class="-yellow submit"></button>
    </form>
```

**The validation code**

```
 $(function() {
    $("form[name='registration']").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.post('my.php', $('#prize-form').serialize());
},
    });
});
```

**The php**

```
$data['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
$data['code'] = $_POST['code'];
$data['checkbox%5B%5D'] = $_POST['agree'];
$data['checkbox1%5B%5D'] = $_POST['agree'];
```

Comment: Try logging XMLHttpRequests in chrome console (or add a console.log) and see if the post is sending or it's failing validation

Comment: @RyanC I added a console.log inside the submitHandler, but there is nothing in the console

Comment: And I am also logging the XMLHttpRequests  and nothing shows up in the log

Comment: Are you sure the `$(form).validate();` code is being ran and you have jquery/jquery-validate included? I ran your code with no issue.